# how to implement method with return type as Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-identity

I am trying to work on a database first approach for the new identity system and I'm currently stumped at one point. This what I have so far

```
    public class MyCustomUserStore<T>: IUserStore<T> where T:ApplicationUser
    {

         public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
        {
            Task<ApplicationUser> taskInvoke = Task<ApplicationUser>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Here is where I will lookup my existing legacy database table
                //setting some dummy value here to the properties added tothe ApplicationUser class
                ApplicationUser obj = new ApplicationUser();
                obj.Id = "userid : " + userId;
                return  obj;
            });

            return  taskInvoke;

        }
     }
```

The error I am getting is

> ```
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser>' 
>     to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>'
> ```

Question 1.) Is my class defined correctly? If yes, how do I proceed further with getting values returned from this method?

Question 2.) Should I even bother with implementing this class's methods or wouldn't it be better if I just extended the UserManager class and overrode all its methods

```
   public class MyCustomUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
   {
   }
```

Comment: Why do you define your method generic at all, if you are creating an instance of `Task<ApplicationUser>` and your class constraints `T` to be an `ApplicationUser`? However, you could try defining your class covariant (`MyCustomUserStore<out T>`).

Comment: I was following this example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Aspnet-Identiy-Core-7475a961

Comment: either you're generic or not. you can leave the constraint there. but anything else which is specific should be changed to T. should probably work then. Keep in mind to do new T() you'll have to add ", new()" as constraint

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
        {
                var obj = new T();
                obj.Id = "userid : " + userId;
                return Task.FromResult(T);
        }
```

Comment: it doesnt. I get the compile error: Error 3 Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint.

Comment: The fix was to change the class definition to where T : ApplicationUser , new() and then in my factory.startnew method do what I was doing above.